# ASP.NET MVC routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having a terrible time with a routing issue.  Hopefully you can help me out.

Here are the URL's that work:

```
http://www.example.com/Stories/Action-Name/StoryName
```

`http://www.example.com/Stories/Action-Name/`  (it automatically redirects to ~/Stories/Action-Name/StoryName which is what I want.

However, if I remove the trailing "**/**" (i.e http://www.example.com/Stories/Action-Name) then it redirects to: `http://www.example.com/StoryName`

I have no idea how or why this is happening.

Here's the route I have setup in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("SurvivorStoriesRedirect", "Stories/Action-Name/{id}", new {
                controller = "Stories",
                action = "Action-Name",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

EDIT --

Not sure what or how I was messing this up but I just added this:

```
routes.MapRoute("SurvivorStoriesRedirect", "Stories/{action}/{id}", new {
                controller = "Stories",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

And removed any other routes for the "Stories" controller, and all seemed to work.

Comment: In all likelihood it's using another route that you've defined.

Comment: I moved that route to the top to see if that was occurring and it still happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to create a route to handle default action calls.  Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute("SurvivorStoriesDefault", "Stories/Action-Name", new {
                controller = "Stories",
                action = "Action-Name"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab Phil Haack's [routedebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) from [NuGet](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/06/introducing-nupack-package-manager.aspx) or download the zip from Phil's [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) and you'll be able to view the matches which won't show you the *why* but you'll see the *how* and soon figure it out.